# Showing that $\mathbb{D}=\{ \frac{p}{10^n}\mid p \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a principal ideal domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> Suppose you have $$ \mathbb{D}=\{ \frac{p}{10^n}\mid p \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$$
>   Show that every ideal of this ring is principal.

So my approach was to first find a potential candidate for an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $a\mathbb{D} = I$. I reasoned first that $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ so of a form $a \mathbb{Z}$, thus then I showed that $a\mathbb{D} \subset I$. Now I need to show that $I \subset a \mathbb{Z}$, and here I have issues. If $x \in I$ then I should somehow find $(p,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ so that $x = a \frac{p}{10^n}$ but I am unable to find a way!

Comment: The number $1/10^n$ is in your ring (only rings have ideals, sets don't). As is $10^n$. So $p/10^n$ is in the ideal if and only if $p$ is. Do you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have that $a\mathbb{Z} = I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ — so you're nearly there!

Let $x=\frac{p}{10^n}\in I$.
Then $p=10^n x\in a\mathbb{Z}$ as $10^n\in\mathbb{D}$. So $a|p$, and there must exist $d=\frac{(p/a)}{10^n}\in\mathbb{D}$ such that $x=ad$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!